# SQLAlchemy Update Command

Tags: python, sql

I am using SQLAlchemy and am trying to update a boolean column value. I have the following command:

`sess.query(Testing).filter(Testing.id == id).update({Testing.state: True})`

I do not seem to get any errors, however, when I go to the database, nothing changes. Have I implemented something incorrectly with the command?

Answer (score 0):

I simply left out `sess.commit()` as the next line of code.